# TimeSpan struct 0.0/1.0 division reasons

Tags: c#, floating-point, timespan

I was looking at the `TimeSpan` struct and it's `TotalDays` property, looking like this:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public double TotalDays
    {
      [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
      {
        return (double) this._ticks * (0.0 / 1.0);
      }
    }
```

My question is, how does this multiplication by (0.0 / 1.0) return the correct amount of days? I do understand that due to the floating point arithmetics we might not get a zero from the forementioned division, but how does that number we get relate to the amount of days? What made me even more confused was the fact that the amount of hours is defined using the same multiplication:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public double TotalHours
    {
      [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
      {
        return (double) this._ticks * (0.0 / 1.0);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Dont look at reflector . Use the reference source . You will see different code

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,d0bc7009a734d3ee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, don't use reflector.  `TimeSpan` is a `struct` not a `class`.

[Total Days Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,d0bc7009a734d3ee)

```
public double TotalDays {
    get { return ((double)_ticks) * DaysPerTick; }
}
```

which differs from [Total Hours Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,b681a346b0dac6d6)

```
public double TotalHours {
    get { return (double)_ticks * HoursPerTick; }
}
```